# Ray/Redis failure on ray.init. Any ideas?

Tags: python, redis, ray

Version: Ray 1.2.0

Searched high and low and I cannot seem to fix this issue.

Not a data size issue and not a server firewall issue. Both ray and redis are running on remote host (linux) - connected to via vscode (linux) remotessh and running *.ipynb file with the code below. I can view ray dashboard http://127.0.0.1:8265 via port forwarding.

Simple code:

```
if ray.is_initialized():
    ray.shutdown()

ray.init(_node_ip_address="0.0.0.0",
    ignore_reinit_error=True)

# Also fails[1]:
# ray.init(address='auto', ignore_reinit_error=True, _redis_password='xxxx')

# Also fails[2]:
# before call to ray.init: 
# ray.services.get_node_ip_address = lambda: '127.0.0.1'
```

Last line of stacktrace:

```
~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/connection.py in send_packed_command(self, command, check_health)
    715                 errno = e.args[0]
    716                 errmsg = e.args[1]
--> 717             raise ConnectionError("Error %s while writing to socket. %s." %
    718                                   (errno, errmsg))
    719         except BaseException:

ConnectionError: Error 32 while writing to socket. Broken pipe.
```

Comment: Appears to be a vscode issue running ipynb file. Running ray.init on remote machine via a terminal works as expected.

Comment: Interesting, is it expected behavior that vscode runs the ipynb locally?

Answer (score 0):

Ray drivers are expected to run on a node in the cluster (usually the head node) and [requires many ports](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-core/configure.html#ports-configurations) which you probably don't want to open up to the internet due to the security implications.

The best way to connect to a remote cluster (for interactive developement is with [Ray Client.](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/cluster/ray-client.html) Note. You'll need to make sure your ray client port is open on the head node.